# finding out bit pattern for 4 bit #

Tags: binary, twos-complement

a. Fill in the bit pattern for the following 4-bit numbers. If there are multiple bit patterns for a number, write them all. If no bit pattern exists, write "N/A" in the box.

Unsigned, sign/magnitude, one's complement, two's complement

for 0,7,-1, 15, and 8.

I figured out those for 0, -1 and 15.

I need help on 7 and 8.

Comment: A signed 8 cannot be represented in 4 bits.

Answer (score 2):

For 7

```
Unsigned notation - 0111
Signed notation - 0111
1s complement notation - 0111 
2s complement notation - 0111
```

For 8

```
Unsigned notation - 1000
Signed notation - N/A  (-7 to +7)
1s complement notation - N/A  (-7 to +7)
2s complement notation - N/A  (-8 to +7)
```

Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)